# JSF <h:selectOneMenu disable selection of items

Tags: jsf-2, selectonemenu

In my current project, i have to show a list of countries using

> `<h:selectOnemenu`

jsf component. However, this collection of countries may contains countries with active flag set to false, which case i should not show those countries in the list for new applications, but if there are any existing applications with those inactive countries, i need to show them.
can anybody tell me how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, i found the solution, actually i should have done more research before posting here the problem. My requirement can be achieved by using `itemDisabled` option of `<f:selectItems` component.